# Function with an inner function called recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have an object describing a menu with submenus at different levels. Before transforming it into HTML, I add an id property that will later be used to generate ids for HTML. Here's the code:

```
    MyModule.recursively_add_id = function myself(arg) {
        let idGenerator = () => { return '_' + (Math.random()*0x1000000000000000) ; }
        if (arg === null)
            return ;
        else if (Array.isArray(arg))
            arg.forEach(element => myself(element)) ;
        else if (typeof arg === 'object') {
            for (let key in arg)
                myself(arg[key]) ;
            arg.id = idGenerator() ;
        }
        else  // number, string...
            return ;
    } ;
```

I never defined an inner function in a function designed to be called recursively, so I wondered, will `idGenerator()` redefined at each call of `recursively_add_id()`? I guess it wouldn't be a great overhead, but I'd like to be sure of what is going on here.

Comment: This isn't specific to recursion - even if you had a non-recursive function `idGenerator` would be created with every call. Because that's how calling a function works - it goes through the code in the function, executing each one.

Comment: @VLAZ, yeah, of course it would be the same if I called it many times in a loop; the point is if I can expect some optimization to be performed

Comment: That would be an implementation detail of the environment. It might, or it might not. If you want it to be correct, then just not define the function inside. It's good practice anyway - doesn't really make sense *logically* to write code that defines functions it uses then throws them away almost immediately.

Comment: Yes, I must confess that I _did_ move it outside, I posted the code with the function inside for the purpose of asking the question. So, maybe your comment _is_ the definite answer?...